# How do I declare a string that is of a specific length using typescript?

Tags: typescript

For example a string that can only be two characters long, which could be used for an ISO country code.

I have used Google and looked through the documentation but cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There isn't a way to specify a string length as a type.

If you have a finite list of country codes, you could write a string literal type:

```
type CountryCode = 'US' | 'CN' | 'CA' | ...(lots of others);
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but using https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data, but I decided against it because it would be overkill given the fact that the country codes will be returned from a backend API. I just want to ensure the variable cannot contain any obviously wrong data and thought it would be simple to specify length. I also thought about using an array but thought of that as somewhat convoluted plus you apparently cannot specify an enforced max length for an array (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/typescript-fixed-length-arraylength-type)

Answer (score 13):

Actually it's possible to do

```
// tail-end recursive approach: returns the type itself to reuse stack of previous call
type LengthOfString<
  S extends string,
  Acc extends 0[] = []
> = S extends `${string}${infer $Rest}`
  ? LengthOfString<$Rest, [...Acc, 0]>
  : Acc["length"];

type IsStringOfLength<S extends string, Length extends number> = LengthOfString<S> extends Length ? true : false

type ValidExample = IsStringOfLength<'json', 4>
type InvalidExapmple = IsStringOfLength<'xml', 4>
```

thanks to

- https://twitter.com/trashh_dev/status/1558827043504078849
- https://twitter.com/anuraghazru/status/1558836599269445637
- https://twitter.com/CodingCarter/status/1558924142379950080

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using a type constructor and a phantom type which are some interesting techniques to learn about. You can see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832231/8069575)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this for strings & arrays.

```
type FixedString<N extends number> = { 0: string, length: N } & string;
type FixedArray<N extends number, T> = { 0: T, length: N } & T[];
```

> Playground: https://tsplay.dev/m3VQkN

String creation requires that you coerce the type, since the string value's length isn't known at assignment. You can bypass that with `as` coercion and/or a factory function for that type.

However, array creation (oddly) can assert the array's length on assignment. So that's nice :)

The playground link (above) also includes the beginnings of some length-checker types.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use template literals and generate all the possible options. [*playground*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXigIgIYagH0wCNcCMBjEzAE0owloDNaBzWgC1oEtKByAKx74oPANaCCPADbjhAWxk8AdgoD2CsAoCOCpAoDOC4AoCuCgG4yMAd1oAPWiFoAvDAChQkKAFUwkJGSw9CDgEZDRvX2QAoIAeEMQkAD5Xd3BoABUrFXjkPXCAAwASAG8cpABfErLy-NTPTJUAYSwwTmAsSTK89CLinz9o4PgEyr7I-0Ch0Ira1zIVRT1gKFsARgAuKAau8J4sQjJBKGOTqAB6M6hAdHI5haWVgCZN7eHc3f2j05OLqEAUclvFssQBstllmq12p1XkhusIAIIAIUagh%20N3mgKgICeoKaLTaHR26B4iKOP3%20rioEDIkiwSGgDGMijIwE4CygnD0KgAFByVM8sl0AJSbLCKEApXlcvYHHiC86XG6S6Wy45koA)

```
type Letter = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm' | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z"
type UppercaseLetter = Uppercase<Letter>

type TwoLetters = `${Letter}${Letter}`
type TwoCapitalLetters = `${UppercaseLetter}${UppercaseLetter}`

const x1: TwoLetters = 'abc'        // ✗
const x2: TwoLetters = 'ab'         // ✔
const y1: TwoCapitalLetters = 'ABC' // ✗
const y2: TwoCapitalLetters = 'AB'  // ✔

declare function iso(iso: TwoLetters): any

iso('abc') // ✗
iso('ab')  // ✔
```

Comment: This is cool, but looks at certain number of combinations TS gives up and makes it type `any`

Comment: @MaximMazurok Then you need to use a function and something like [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699053/how-do-i-declare-a-string-that-is-of-a-specific-length-using-typescript#77355345).

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to have type of string with limited set of letters. But it's probably an overkill anyway, so ended up just using string type

Comment: @MaximMazurok I added another playground to the other linked answer above that uses **custom character sets**, although it has very limited usability. Mostly a fun experiment. The TS playground link is too long for a comment, so I had to include it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go a bit fancy, even with a custom Error type.
*[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPIDMAyE3AAsAeGKCAD2DwBMBnKWhFVAGimzMpvuQFcBbAEYR4APigBednlSES4ilWR12UAPywoALlhM0ufAQCi8eAHt4AfSPlIAYyrUDs4tlEAod9Qh2ANgEN4aExeZAdEM2QoRFozEk4lFUYkNFEAChizHTgUjBwZORg2ACZRAEodf2QQT0y0gCJyEAAverKoAHoOqEB0cigAchzmZ0ITcysbe0cR4lL+9zr6u1b2rqhAFHJPdw6AKihQSCgCCF9IeHodjs8D6BgwX0RgeMVuBj1UcSlSF+V6AAMACQAbxQmBEUAAqgBfYGg8EANShf3UUAA2hC2AA6bF3B5PeGiAC62jRhPcN2khmeXF+b1yn1g90e8lR-V8BQI-TJ5PAt3eMzGFmsth80w5RA4PxUfCEIgZQLpzEs7MMln4vEYlmEOg4UKAA)*

```
declare function iso<S extends string>(iso: StringOfLength<S, 2>): any

iso("xyz") // ✗ 'StringLengthError_ExpectedLength<2>'
iso("cz")  // ✔
```

```
type StringOfLength<S extends string, L extends number> = Length<S> extends L ? S : StringLengthError_ExpectedLength<L>

type Split<S extends string> = S extends `${infer U}${infer V}` ? [U, ...Split<V>] : []
type Length<S extends string> = Split<S>['length']

type StringLengthError_ExpectedLength<L extends number> = { string_length_must_be: L }
```

---

And here [*(playground)*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAUG1gKgFgUzAewHYBsCeYAOKBnAgSwCMNkBXAxAYwEMaxiC9CAXAWgFsUAndom4AaKDHZZciArT7Fc7MLRTdcxCnzAB1AJIAZPWAAmiQbUXt4LMIj59+YemiN57AN2ImwVtIoDu8PSKaIiIRqzsKGCkyABmxAAeYaIwjhgxxIrEaI452UbEfHT+9FgAdBAgwBAQymgEisoYDgC8YADkAMSxsQAM7bXoDWB+9mgA5mBtXT0J7WDAwGAAPJxgltbWo+jjNRJSSki0ANZTkKkAZGAAwkfHy-uIKLFKKM18wmAAavQYnkGIB6SJ4vJr8T7XN78ADKpgAfHCFktALwbgA-dsTQK63Oj3R7PEZjcafH5-IwAoFSfHbCYQqF8WHsBFIsCAdHIwGsNqxrAQVIh4Cg-ASdp9xlFaHd1khjIh4mhMsR0HtgTc7ssAIKfABCNgSgmcrA1YDVAH0dXrwmBtW1NYi2iE3LYaqA4NJ-Jl4OtgawqkqDgAJRAJM4AIl6AEYAEwAZgALABWABsAHYABwATjVmuuABEAKIAMXopFoJliwYgjxudIZZwA2sHOsHPgGEs3A22EgBdCvKgAaZxJ-0EyxmfXatPeDMRizAaJ7BwAmgPfkPAaO5hOYfDmWy1kVaIhiA6XMGEsGdVJzGEwKHI7G42VH+WIM7YK6Ru6wLFKGhzAr6mAP6xPw7A-gC2DGCg0hoO0-j8KcPoQN+v7sP+YBuCuZKCNC7ByBMWjurc9B8PQV58AQyxESRZFqnYpRmog+pgA0eHjLWnZwgAFAAlGAADeYBFKBfA5Ms0IMUxLHZOMXEsQAXN8mHktCEKBNRgh8LRJFYHCvEtIiLFgAAvkhP5-ugimkgCOGsWqBCQu8YkSRaUkTLJuEKYOWGAipVaTvCvECUJlAicxuHGTUdTDAkYZnBhVnYbh0kEZYVGkRpFEOVujI8YM9SKAkEZnDFnGjv0vEzgg3L8pQGAuGgKCKOMR7IE4Nh2PwkVDAVUbLgliA2dJdlZXwpXdGOFVLFVrAEDVdVgA1TUtbk7X2HwTrgGAiGVl5ynOTNSU0iqxGsIG5oHax7G2pZq7GmJqknXC87ILtgh3eJZ2MS5h1Esd5H7WFl2dp8ADycjNWgvwA65kxtL5AAKhDyhZn2ST9ZztO010YmAeiMeMlhiYiqMWr05ypDAAD8f0ELW7QUBMljtJ2ANk9TYPEBDUMKYNEwALIsNwQTirmHV8MsAb0EYRMPeRta9MDYAc1zGCfIjJCoegT0UzACmS9L0LE7qX2sFRBCwCgACqcroJRam0wriI4zr0DU69iB3QASq6MtgN7DSwJQuAUHbj2g+D2S-J8AAGAAkfHq8jaBGWA0dOy7FM8z9AsEEL7Ai2LEuIFLvtm-LivK5HqtgInmtoE9L7gJWSAYFI-3bcq+tOSTF3SddH3G0xcd8dksS2GAltGfHMNGdHYDU5bYAKZjz1+z7A-nYDfdnBvJup9PP1TyPaBj5ok9zwvS8dAMlb++wgfB4CaoA04WBXWcz892Atav58j5lKPceXwWZuyvuxX0yBoTB0yN3Qe31WL9wBsPQBZ8j4oO+LPee39LZ-0fFAv47BlhfDhCzBS4DKx40ZvAWBm8Yb92gYQw2dMGYE3gMzCBNMLbW3-DQvedCziUNYUTVmWD7Tjz1sXA2iIAA+nCrY2zQMsO+RMG6Vl5uMHOecC5rSUXQQ8x5oY-U+LmBIl5BAuC-jDcOnMq6GNYmrJGdc7HSWMWLM4QU9EtSMApb2B4vGfEDGYsICkTFBJcEZa6fEca2DWsvdRmjhbwFFmtAYqR9z6OCWvPxx5ommOKJk0J+SLFwNYD+Us2RrzU0xlfQpV4jA43kkrCOkMMA43wAQBSw9a7-iMgAPWjhAIyQA) is another ***experiment*** using custom character sets.

```
type Hex = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
type ColorSet = ["#", Hex, Hex, Hex]
type X = Validate<'#ff0', ColorSet> // 
type Y = Validate<'#ffx', ColorSet> // ✗ - received "x" expected "012345..."
```