# Typescript is it possible to declare a generic type for an array of 1-N strings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

A bit hard to explain it in the title but basically, I'd like to be able to declare a type  array of fixed length strings from 1 to N:

```
interface Command {
  [key: string]: (args: [string, ...string[]]) => boolean;
}

const cmd: Command = {
  TEST: (args: [string, string]) => args[0] === args[1],
  TEST2: (args: [string]) => args[0] === 'hello'
}
```

so this doesn't work as [string, string] is different from string[]:

`Type '(args: [string]) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(args: [string, ...string[]]) => boolean'.`

A solution could be to define like all kind of arguments:

```
interface Command {
  [key: string]: (args: [string] | [string, string] | [string, string, string]) => boolean;
}
```

But a bit too verbose for something simple (agreed it can be encapsulated in an interface), anyway is there another elegant solution to this that I'm not seeing?

Thanks,

Comment: No it's not possible. Typescript doesn't supports types with specified string length. But there maybe something that can help you, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832231/7616528

Comment: Your "verbose" solution doesn't work either, right?  It gives the same error.  I'm not really sure what you want `Command` to look like.  Can you show how you would plan to use a value `c` of type `Command`?  Say, you have the function `c.f`... are you allowed to call it with `c.f(["hello"])`? Can you call it with `c.f(["hello","goodbye"])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you actually need `Command` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so that its properties can actually be used.  If you have a function type like `(arg: [string] | [string, string]) => boolean`, then you cannot implement it with a `(arg: [string]) => boolean` or with a `(arg: [string, string]) => boolean`.  Function types vary [contravariantly](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in their arguments' types.  You can widen, but not narrow, the type of a function argument.  Unless you want to require that all methods of type `Command` must accept *every* possible string array of length one or more, you have to do something with generics.

Here's a possible type for `Command`, along with a helper function `asCommand()` which lets the compiler infer the proper value of `T` given a value of type `Command<T>` without forcing you to write it out yourself:

```
type Command<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (args: T[K]) => boolean }

const asCommand = <T extends Record<keyof T, [string, ...string[]]>>(
    cmd: Command<T>
) => cmd;
```

Then, your `cmd` constant can be declared like this with no errors:

```
const cmd = asCommand({
    TEST: (args: [string, string]) => args[0] === args[1],
    TEST2: (args: [string]) => args[0] === 'hello'
});
```

and the compiler remembers that `cmd.TEST` takes a pair and `cmd.TEST2` takes a one-tuple:

```
cmd.TEST(["", ""]); // okay
cmd.TEST([]); // error
cmd.TEST([""]); // error
cmd.TEST(["", "", ""]); // error

cmd.TEST2([""]); // okay
cmd.TEST2([]); // error
cmd.TEST2(["", ""]); // error
cmd.TEST2(["", "", ""]); // error
```

And you're not allowed to give a property that accepts only zero-length tuples:

```
const badCmd = asCommand({
    OOPS: (args: []) => false, // error!
})
```

I hope that gives you some direction; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMA8AVAfFAXigG8oBtAaSgEtUoBrCEOAMymwF0AuKACmQBOAcwDOPbJQ4BKQvgBGcOABsIaKAF8AUJoDGcVCOBRkI+EjTpCUHFAgAPYBAwioAJQh6BWRszbYANOSGArRCgQB0kcGhZBwcuLi8mlApUDoI6DxmKBg4uJoyBPjp6ADc2noGRiVWJtkWvMTJqdgAogDK2Dz8wmJBwCGoYVDRQ9Kyxr1kAAwchAREgqJkAIwc-s0pbZ0ATN1LfWSjQuNFk8uz80QA5AAWEEpKcNea6lLluhnh29i8ZABE-0CgOkpSgAHpwVA4PRkCBPuhvh1frF3hCoRABAI4AIEUjOn8QWjIbYsTi8T9CUCoIDgf9QejSdiBFAKl8fjsqQySTC4RTkZzUWCSZjmfzdlS6dyMWTcSV8dhBbSadSicKZWLdPpDFA5Mh0DAMrVTIgcuhGpsoAB5K0ABXa+16PFRExYyCUIgggRFsoAhK8pJogA)