# Extract info from Typescript type

Tags: typescript, string, primitive

*I'm new to Typescript, so probably not using the terminology right... bear with me*

#### Background

I've been trying to extend primitives such as `string` with moderate success. I am even able to store some custom type info on my extended string, like this:

```
// yes, we can extends strings!
type ExtendStr<P extends string = string, MaxLen extends number = 0> = P & { parent: P, options: { max: MaxLen } }

// create a LongStr with max length of 256
type LongStr = ExtendStr<string, 256>
```

I am able to retrieve the extra info that I stored in the type information, like this:

```
// get the max length of a LongStr
type LongStrMax = LongStr['options']['max']
// yields 256... Hoorah!
```

I can even extend `LongStr` and get correctly working type widening/narrowing:

```
// make a ShortStr that extends LongStr but has max length 8
type ShortStr = ExtendStr<LongStr, 8>

// two example variables
let short: ShortStr = 'Hello' as ShortStr 
let long: LongStr = 'Omg this is a very long string!!' as LongStr 

// widening conversion is allowed as it should
long = short 

// narrowing conversion gives compiler error... sweet! 
short = long
```

However, this seems to 'hide' the stored info...

#### Now the question

I want to get at the stored `'max'` for the `ShortStr`. I see it there in the type info...

But when I try to get it...

```
type ShortStrMax = ShortStr['options']['max']
```

..it yields `never`.... **is there a way???**

#### [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AABhgkCxsRfb9q6r5Ihu4AAPxMakQA)

Comment: You’re aware of the reason right? `8 & 256` should be `never`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NByaVw) meet your needs?  Instead of representing the max length you represent a union of acceptable lengths, so the intersection works the way you want (instead of `8 & 256`=`never` you get `(0|1|...|7|8)&(0|1|...|255|256)`=`(0|1|...|7|8)`.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Can't wait to see some wizardry 

Comment: The semantic of your current impl is really describing "fixed sized string" rather than  "string with max length". And reason why TS allows `long = short` is only a coincident, because `short.options.max == never` and `never` can be assigned to anything.

Comment: If you define `ShortStr` first, then `type LongStr = ExtendStr<ShortStr, 256>`, now you'll see `short = long` is allowed, but not `long = short`, which I doubt is what you want. Thus I think jcalz's solution is the right way to go.

Comment: @jcalz That seems quitte brilliant, Thank you! Still got to wrap my head around it but this looks very promising indeed!

Comment: @jcalz Did not notice right away, but your solution actually addresses 2 questions I had. You show how to get at the `max` property (and how to store it so you can retrieve it later), but your solution actually also narrows/widens correctly! Mine only did if I created a complex hierarchy. Yours does it really based on the length you filled in. That's brilliant stuff!  Please post this as an answer so I can accept it and we can all give you the *rep* you so obviously deserve  :)

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get the chance, hopefully soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
type ShortStr = ExtendStr<LongStr, 8>
```

and

```
long = short
```

it seems you'd like a `ShortStr` to be a *subtype* of `LongStr`.  That is, every string of 8 or fewer characters *is also* a string of 256 or fewer characters.  That makes sense.  But your definition of `ExtendStr<T, N>` says that there will be an `options.max` property of type `N`.  A `ShortStr` would therefore need to have an `options.max` property whose value is *both* `8` *and* `256`.  There's no value of this type, so this property type is equivalent to  [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) and things start behaving strangely.

---

Conceptually it makes more sense to imagine the `length` property of the string.  A value of `ExtendStr<string, 256>` should have a `length` property whose value is some non-negative whole number less than or equal to `256`.  You can represent this as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 254 | 255 | 256`.  And `ExtendString<string, 8>` should have a `length` property of type `0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 6 | 7 | 8`.  Now it's definitely possible for a string to have a `length` property of *both* those types, since the latter is strictly a subtype of the former.  So if we can programmatically generate the right union type of numbers given `N`, we can write `ExtendStr` in terms of it.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type LessThan<N extends number, A extends number[] = []> =
    N extends A['length'] ? A[number] : LessThan<N, [A['length'], ...A]>;

type LessThanOrEqual<N extends number> = N | LessThan<N>
```

The `LessThan<N>` type is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that turns a number [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `10` into a union of the nonnegative integers less than it by building up a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of these values and stopping when the tuple has length `N`.  So `5` would become `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` which becomes `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.

And `LessThanOrEqual<N>` is just the union of `N` with `LessThan<N>`, so `LessThanOrEqual<5>` is `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5`.

And now `ExtendStr`:

```
type ExtendStr<P extends string = string, MaxLen extends number = 0> =
    P &  { length: LessThanOrEqual<MaxLen> }
```

Note that instead of creating phantom `parent` and `options.max` properties, I just use the string type itself and the existing `length` property.  You could keep it your way if you want, but I don't see much of a use for it in this example.  It's up to you.

One more thing... you want to be able to extract the maximum length from the type.  That is, given `ExtendStr<string, N>`, you'd like to retrieve `N`.  Right now if you inspect the `length` property you get a big union, and you just want the maximum member of that union.  Well, you can do that like this:

```
type Max<N extends number> = Exclude<N, LessThan<N>>
```

That works because `LessThan<3 | 5>` will be `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4` and `Exclude<3 | 5, 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4>` is `5`.

---

So, let's try it:

```
type LongStr = ExtendStr<string, 256>

type LongStrMax = Max<LongStr['length']>
/* type LongStrMax = 256 */

type ShortStr = ExtendStr<LongStr, 8>

let short: ShortStr = 'Hello' as ShortStr
let long: LongStr = 'Omg this is a very long string!!' as LongStr

long = short // okay
short = long // error

type ShortStrMax = Max<ShortStr['length']>;
//type ShortStrMax = 8
```

Looks good!

---

The above works well enough for me, but recursive conditional types can be tricky and sometimes cause compiler performance issues.  If that happens you might want to revert to your current version and then deal with the problem some other way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhDO8AqALAhgOwDwDkoQA9gIMATeKDAVwFsAjCAJwBooBBfIk8y2hxgNoBdKAF4owgHxiAUFHlQ8hYmQpsBAcgA2JAObAUGkQH52A6vSYiAXLATJ02HKwHrteg0dYA6X2yGSANwyMqCQdoiomADyjACiAI5UaFq4nCo8FvzS4nCRjrjSAD6KIWHQALJoBGnK3BRZTDlQcQQAxlpUpBC4rHkOmIWSZeDQrRkAysCMWAAK6fVQ8NMAlhi6Ykur66xVBHAYC6q8loybAAw5cgrzAGTyAN5QOusGtv1RGLGJyal7B9IAL5QEIAelBUDajAgaGIUDQsAA9uspmcAO4rAxQGjVZ4eFBQREAMygACYAKwANlCoyRKOmm3G3FRWGWjDWulYFMpwxk4KguggwCgBmgOIIeNeBOJ8LpulRNPCMGR8ume02eywyvpgncUqMw1BACoRbTtarGAdNtyoEbQWCITiANbQBETFCIxjAVEi9DCurHc0+uhUYXoCjiyX6AkADkV0Hdnu9DPETLILKD01YMd5-OAaMRnDQNDAOigADc0Oy0HQdPAZDphfAPV7bImvT7xBoABIQLRaREaeEUdvJxgNoXPFXvFWdqAaaI0DYGFYUVey8tMEBT9ZbdnrACEB6HaAomfHfIhGO6GA5kORm8Y8BWyKg65SA7REFIw7fTY9VBaKQDYqpszZJg6lBVowiIYrubQPkwz6vroKybhQCElisOhnEwMGML43hLF+QoHiC4FepsA7rCM4Sjqi6riJq9HTJoLzRgawTguUUAsYwjFQHGIRAA)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the String type to have a max/min length is not completely trivial. You can see this question about how to do it [Declaring string type with min/max length in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813272/declaring-string-type-with-min-max-length-in-typescript)

What is going wrong with your types starts here

```
type ShortStr = ExtendStr<LongStr, 8>
```

You can inspect the type and see what ShortStr gets expanded into

```
type ShortStr = string & {
    parent: string;
    options: {
        max: 256;
    };
} & {
    parent: LongStr;
    options: {
        max: 8;
    };
}
```

You can see that the options properties are not compatible with each other, because the `max` property is deemed by the compiler to not ever be able to satisfy `max === 8` and `max === 256`.

Therefore, `options` gets reduced to `never`, but you can still access `parent`, since the types are compatible.

```
type ShortStrParent = ShortStr['parent']
// expands to
type ShortStrParent = string & {
    parent: string;
    options: {
        max: 256;
    };
}
```