# Typescript, type with lengh information

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with a simple string property.

```
export interface Foo {
  Bar: string;
}
```

I would need to store some extra information in this string type. --> The allowed length. The coding could then react on this extra property (e.g. do a `.substring(0, maxlength)`

I thought about having a decorator, but this does not work on interfaces

```
export interface Foo {
  @Length(200)
  Bar: string;
}
```

Do you have any other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a string that is of a specific length using typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699053/how-do-i-declare-a-string-that-is-of-a-specific-length-using-typescript)

Comment: You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673001/define-a-type-in-typescript-with-conditional-properties-limits/49673307#49673307.