# error while compiling in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
private seats: number[][] = [[10],[10]];
        for(let i:number=0; i < 10; i++)
        for(let j:number=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                this.seats[i][j] = '_';
            }
```

This is giving me an error

**this.seats[i][j] = '_"
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**
 how do i solve it?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Comment: i have gone through it but I could not find anything... i Am getting an error **this.seats[i][j] = '-';
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined** @jonrsharpe

Comment: Then give a [mcve] **of that attempt**. It looks like you've created an empty array as `seats`, in which case `seats[i]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: can you please code it for me ? @jonrsharpe would be of great help. I want the above code in typescript it is in java

Comment: No; SO is **not** a code-writing service. Also that's not JavaScript; if it was, it would *already work* in TypeScript, which is a superset of JS.

Comment: i have just defined it as **private seats: number[][] = [[10],[10]]; for(let i:number=0; i < 10; i++)
            for(let j:number=0;j<10;j++)
                this.seats;
                {
                    this.seats[i][j] = '_';
                }
                
    }** For this i am getting the above error @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please [edit] the question with correct formatting. But obviously that won't work, `[10]` doesn't create an array of length ten, it creates an array of length one with a single number in it. Again, read the basic documentation about the language you're trying to use; guessing is unlikely to be terribly productive.

Comment: I have editted it @jonrsharpe

Comment: You have, but I've already told you why that won't work. You want to create an array of length ten, not an array with ten in it, so see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41139763/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're creating a 2d `number` array. So you can't assign `_` as it is a string. Secondly, you're not initializing the secondary array

Try the following code:

```
private seats: number[][] = []; // 2d array is just an array

for(let i:number=0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.seats[i] = []; // you need to init the inner array

    for(let j:number=0; j<10; j++) {
        this.seats[i][j] = i;
    }
}
```