# Tuple with fixed length

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

Typescript in tuple allows to add extra elements with any of types used before, but I would like to limit the length. I've tried with `& { length: 2 }`, [but it didn't helped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20var%20a%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D%20%26%20%7B%20length%3A%202%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa%5B0%5D%20%3D%20%221%22%0D%0Aa%5B1%5D%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Aa%5B2%5D%20%3D%20%223%22%3B%0D%0Aa%5B3%5D%20%3D%204%3B):

```
declare var a: [string, number] & { length: 2 };

a[0] = "1"
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = "3";
a[3] = 4;
```

Assignments for `[2]` and `[3]` don't produce error. How can I specify corresponding type?

Comment: Some solutions here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/typescript-fixed-length-arraylength-type/59906630#59906630

Comment: @colxi, actually there is no such problem starting from version 3.1.

Comment: Tuples do not prevent you from adding/deleting  keys after Array initialization, but there are solutions to implement a safe FixedLengthArray type signatures

Comment: @colxi, yep, I've understood your answer to that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use type [`never` for array tail](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20var%20a%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%2C%20...never%5B%5D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa%5B0%5D%20%3D%20%221%22%0D%0Aa%5B1%5D%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Aa%5B2%5D%20%3D%20%223%22%3B%0D%0Aa%5B3%5D%20%3D%204%3B):

```
declare var a: [string, number, ...never[]];
```

and you'll get

> Type '"3"' is not assignable to type 'never'.

> Type '4' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Typescript 4.1 or newer, you can utilize [Recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) to create tuple types with flexible length:

```js
type TupleOf<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;
```

which allows you to easily specify the value type and length of your tuple

```js
type T1 = TupleOf<string, 3>;
```

Then such tuple would compile

```js
const tuple: T1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

whereas this one wouldn't

```js
const tuple: T1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

```
TS2322: Source has 4 element(s) but target allows only 3
```

The downside is of course that you can't easily specify different types in the tuple, so this approach is rather suitable for single-typed tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typescript 3.1 or newer you don't need to add special limitations to tuples:

```
declare var a: [string, number];
```

---

You may notice that code

```
declare var a: [string, number];

a[0] = "1"
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = "3";
a[3] = 4;
```

[compiles in 3.0.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.0.1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8oC54G0DOAXGAlgHYDmANPEQK4C2ARiDALoDcAUG1JgAxPwC88AEQBGIZ0wi+ggEzsuM6cIDMQ+ZmVKALCyA) but [doesn't compile in 3.1.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.1.6#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8oC54G0DOAXGAlgHYDmANPEQK4C2ARiDALoDcAUG1JgAxPwC88AEQBGIZ0wi+ggEzsuM6cIDMQ+ZmVKALCyA) with messages

> Index '2' is out-of-bounds in tuple of length 2.
>   Index '3' is out-of-bounds in tuple of length 2.