# Unordered tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am just digging into Typescript typings and I wondered how to define a type which is a tuple but with unordered element types.

I mean, having

```
type SimpleTuple = [number, string];

const tup1: SimpleTuple = [7, `7`]; // Valid
const tup2: SimpleTuple = [`7`, 7]; // 'string' is not assignable to 'number'
                                    // and vice-versa
```

This is useful in many cases, but what if I don't care about order or I need it to be unordered.
The example above is quite trivial since I could define

```
type SimpleUnorderedTuple = [number, string] | [string, number];

const tup1: SimpleUnorderedTuple = [7, `7`]; // Valid
const tup2: SimpleUnorderedTuple = [`7`, 7]; // Valid
```

However, I may have a bunch of types... A combinatory logic uppon them would be painful

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just' | 'for' | 'the' | 'example';
type ComplexUnorderedTuple =
    ['these', 'are', 'some', 'words', 'just', 'for', 'the', 'example'] |
    ['these', 'are', 'some', 'words', 'just', 'for', 'example', 'the'] |
    // and so on ...
```

This is insane. There are `!n` possible combinations, where `n` is the number of elements (I guess, I am not too good at maths!).

I am trying to achieve something like

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some';
type UnorderedTuple<T> = ; //...

type ComplexUnorderedTuple = UnorderedTuple<ABunchOfTypes>;
```

I found in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/typescript-tuples)

> Any subsequent value we add to the tuple variable can be any of the predefined tuple types in no particular order.

But I couldn't reproduce. If I define a tuple of two elements, I am not allowed to access to the nth position, if `n` is greater than (or equal) the tuple length.

Comment: A tuple is nothing more than an array with a specified length and type of every element. Since you explicitly don't want the specified type part from a tuple, then I believe what you are looking for is actually a way to [declare a fixed length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript).

Comment: I want the specified type. If I declare a type to be `['word1', 'word2']` I am constraining the tuple to contain only these two words. It's just I don't care the order of them. Declaring a fixed-length-array won't solve this because it could admit the repetition of elements `['word1', 'word2']` which I don't want.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60762482/9614175), it seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: You wrote "If I define a tuple of two elements, I am not allowed to access to the nth position, if n is greater than (or equal) the tuple length." so it seems you don't need a two elements tuple, but something else. Please provide some more examples of valid data you need

Comment: This feels a lot like an XY problem, but... does this help? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-654906323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for permutation type of a union, this will give you exactly that:

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just';

type PushFront<TailT extends any[], HeadT> =
    ((head: HeadT, ...tail: TailT) => void) extends ((...arr: infer ArrT) => void) ? ArrT : never;

type CalculatePermutations<U extends string, ResultT extends any[] = []> = {
    [k in U]: (
        [Exclude<U, k>] extends [never] ?
        PushFront<ResultT, k> :
        CalculatePermutations<Exclude<U, k>, PushFront<ResultT, k>>
    )
}[U];

var test: CalculatePermutations<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'these', 'just', 'words', 'some'];
```

You can try it in this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgVwHYGMAWB5AZgFXBAZygF4oByYNQiMqAH3IEMAnG+8ggewFs2GyA7p2YATArX4ArBAWBkA3AChFoSFAAKMtADFmnJMAA8ORgEsANjigQAHsAhIxURkhABtALoAaKAAkIjCI4AHwkigCQABSRVIEAXH4BQT4AdGnAZuYJJhY4AJQkoQBunKYiBbb2jkTRaSkszAmmSFgQzLDMzPmFUCVlBQD8HV1QCUgQRW1KKvhQAMKM5igI5oz26m3cCBnApvoEhgCq1nYOTrLMzQDmPgBKhCvAVpVnRC7uHiRQnqGkAN4RNwAaygzSghw8CUiEXCbgAojYUOYECIIEcfEDgp8XtVvuNJsxPgMYZoCDo9AZDPcCI8cBjQnEYQslis1hANswtjs9kgDgikSi0Yd6T5SeT9EZqbT6cEInlFABfNwQ6ZFFhQeyyBLM5ardabbZrHkHeDIdDYPCQAi-b5kFg0HwUKgEB3kaSyMiOoSicSOri8MgeeRAA).

There is a limitation to this approach, however; my experiment showed that TypeScript can at most process a union of 7 strings. With 8 or more strings, an error will shown.

## Update

If "no repetition" is what is needed, it is a lot simpler.

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just';

type PushFront<TailT extends any[], HeadT> =
    ((head: HeadT, ...tail: TailT) => void) extends ((...arr: infer ArrT) => void) ? ArrT : never;

type NoRepetition<U extends string, ResultT extends any[] = []> = {
    [k in U]: PushFront<ResultT, k> | NoRepetition<Exclude<U, k>, PushFront<ResultT, k>>
}[U];

// OK
var test: NoRepetition<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'these', 'just', 'words', 'some'];
test = ['are', 'these', 'just'];
test = ['are'];

// Not OK
test = ['are', 'these', 'are'];
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgVwHYGMAWB5AZgFXBAZygF4oByYNQiMqAH3IEMAnG+8ggewFs2GyA7p2YATArX4ArBAWBkA3AChFoSFAAKMtADFmnJMAA8ORgEsANjigQAHsAhIxURkhABtALoAaKAAkIjCI4AHwkigCQABSRVIEAXH4BQT4AdGnAZuYJJhY4AJQkoQBunKYiBbb2jkTRaSkszAmmSFgQzLDMzPmFUCVlBQD8HV1QCUgQRW1KKvhQAHKcAEoQkMCma-qGAKrWdg5OsszNAOY+ywQI5sBWlftELu4eJFCeoaQA3hFuANZQzVBbDwJTQEHR6AyGc6Xa4+b6hBgLZardamTYAURsKHMCBEEG2sOCPhBYP0RihVxwBOCigAvm5AdMAPSMqAYADSiiKLCg9lkCURKwgaw2SEM8GQ6GweEgBDeLzILBoPgoVAISvI0lkZGVQlE4mVXF4ZA8Sl5wGebgVrG15Eo1BtZE1chNKkI5tIlsVxqZLIW5vZrtkFqt6pV9uVXpNQA).

Also, with the upcoming TypeScript 4 syntax, it can be simplified still:

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just';

// for TypeScript 4 
type NoRepetition<U extends string, ResultT extends any[] = []> = {
    [k in U]: [k, ...ResultT] | NoRepetition<Exclude<U, k>, [k, ...ResultT]>
}[U];

// OK
var test: NoRepetition<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'these', 'just', 'words', 'some'];
test = ['are', 'these', 'just'];
test = ['are'];

// Not OK
test = ['are', 'these', 'are'];
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgVwHYGMAWB5AZgFXBAZygF4oByYNQiMqAH3IEMAnG+8ggewFs2GyA7p2YATArX4ArBAWBkA3AChFAehVQswqHkgBlFMwCWYYFAAsURaEhQAcpwBKESMEOvOSADwBVKBAAewBBIYlCyRkgA5gA0UE4ECAA2wDh+gcGhjEggANoAuiRQ+QB8hQDeigCQOQDWUIZIUN55AFxFNbEAdN3xSSkFDPZOLm6GHp4Aov4oiQgiED6xNcWxtV09hH04ecWKAL45zUqq6hgA0ooAbixQQbJtQ84Qru5e8Mjo2DqEpaQ5ZCwaLEKFQCEDyNJZGRgUJROJgVxeGQ8ko7qY-gDWNDyJRqNiyJC5CirIR0UVMTRiSc7JxTOcSbJCv9AfjcWD8SyUUA).

## Update 2

The above two assumes that you require the array to be non-empty. If you also want to allow empty array, you can do it like this:

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just';

// for TypeScript 4 
type NoRepetition<U extends string, ResultT extends any[] = []> = ResultT | {
    [k in U]: NoRepetition<Exclude<U, k>, [k, ...ResultT]>
}[U];

// OK
var test: NoRepetition<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'these', 'just', 'words', 'some'];
test = ['are', 'these', 'just'];
test = ['are'];
test = [];

// Not OK
test = ['are', 'these', 'are'];
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQgVwHYGMAWB5AZgFXBAZygF4oByYNQiMqAH3IEMAnG+8ggewFs2GyA7p2YATArX4ArBAWBkA3AChFAehVQswqHkgBlFMwCWYYFAAsURaEhQAcpwBKESMEOvOSADwBVKBAAewBBIYlCyRkgA5gA0UE4ECAA2wDh+gcGhjEggANoAuiRQ+QB8hfFJKewA3ooAkDkA1lCGSFDeeQBcdo7OEK7uXgCi-iiJCCIQPrENxbGNsQB0S+XJOHnFigC+Oe1KquoYANKKAG4sUEGyXfZOLm6GHp7wyOjYOoSlpDlkLDSxFFQCH9yNJZGR-kJROJ-lxeGQ8kpLqYvj9WODyJRqOiyKC5AirIRkUVUTR8UjCvk9mpuqYjgTZBSSdjMUDsb94fIgA).

It is possible to replace `U extends string` by `U extends keyof any` to support union types of strings, numbers and symbols, but the current limitation of TypeScript makes it impossible to go beyond this.

Comment: Hi, @Mu-Tsun. That's a very good point and quite accurate. The 7-strings constraint is not a problem, indeed. The only thing I really miss is how to make optional tuple-elements. I mean, having the same example above, how to make `const t: Type<Types>` = ['are']` valid. Thanks!

Comment: That's an awesome answer. I would never figured it out! And yeah, I will use it like `U extends string | number | symbol`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome solution, but If `ABunchOfTypes` contains 9 or more than 9 words, a `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.` error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

[Mu-Tsun Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953396/mu-tsun-tsai)'s answer seems to be a good starting point.

```
type ABunchOfTypes = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words' | 'just';

type PushFront<TailT extends any[], HeadT> =
((head: HeadT, ...tail: TailT) => void) extends ((...arr: infer ArrT) => void) ? ArrT : never;

type CalculatePermutations<U extends string, ResultT extends any[] = []> = {
    [k in U]: (
        [Exclude<U, k>] extends [never] ?
        PushFront<ResultT, k> :
        CalculatePermutations<Exclude<U, k>, PushFront<ResultT, k>>
    ) | PushFront<ResultT, k>
}[U];

var test1: CalculatePermutations<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'these', 'just', 'words', 'some'];
var test2: CalculatePermutations<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'just', 'words'];
// next gives error
var test3: CalculatePermutations<ABunchOfTypes> = ['are', 'are'];
```

Comment: Hi, @Daniele. The point of the question is the constraint of type appearance, not the length of the tuple. In your example, `const d: T = ['are', 'are']` is valid, which I don't want it to be because of the repetition.

Comment: So @VRoxa what you need is a variable length array where each type of `ABunchOfTypes` can appear only once, is it right?

Comment: That's exactly it, yeah.

Comment: @DanieleRicci I appreciate that you found my answer inspiring, but it can actually go simpler than that; check out the update of my answer.

Comment: Gr8 job @Mu-TsunTsai! I already upvoted your answer, I would have upvoted once again! But I want to launch you another challenge: are able to give us a solution with following: `type ABunchOfTypes = 'some' | 'types' | number;` ?

Comment: @DanieleRicci Sure! The trick is to replace `U extends string` by `U extends keyof any`, and then you can use string, number, or symbol in your union. Unfortunately you can't go beyond that, due to the limitation of indices in TypeScript.

Comment: Simply awesome @Mu-TsunTsai !

Answer (score 0):

Create an `enumerate` function like this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]]

type MustInclude<T, U extends T[]> =
  [T] extends [ValueOf<U>]
    ? U
    : never;

const enumerate = <T>() =>
  <U extends NonEmptyArray<T>>(...elements: MustInclude<T, U>) =>
    elements;
```

Usage:

```
type Word = 'these' | 'are' | 'some' | 'words';

const test1 = enumerate<Word>()('are', 'some', 'these', 'words');
const test2 = enumerate<Word>()('words', 'these', 'are', 'some');
const test3 = enumerate<Word>()('these', 'are', 'some', 'words');
```

- ✅ Empty lists are not allowed
- ✅ All values must be present
- ✅ Duplicates are not allowed
- ✅ Every value must be a `Word`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=5&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QPIDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEAe3WIF0BuAWAChXRIoA5KgOwFEAtmFABBAE7i4IHPiIlsAGigA6NaTp1W7cNACySAM7AAkrwDGyACYQcygKpQIAD2AReVw8RJ05rKFAKdE6u7p6B8MhoWPa4WiwBAQD8UPb+iQBcULwQAG4Q4sxsLOZ8xk68SIIFcG6EULIAFACUhLjpmI4ubh5ePALCYpLSsriNaioQCBDVvMCGWQbGZpZINnapuK0E7QmJ+1Mz7vNFOpwA6lTiVvUA5MAAFhCGELdQAD5Qt3Dirx9fhio1Ten1uAHcrp5bqcSmVgFA3MYAIz1dxVGpuTCXa5jZqNb6-W7KW6A4HEx7PV7EiHXQy3ZpFUq8cqI4AAJlRlWqUkx2KsuPxNKh5KeLyJXx+VIBQNeDNYTJZz2AAGZOeiebY+QL7qKpQS9aS9UK6QygA)

Comment: Actually your code does not eliminates duplicates; it just says that every value must be presented. Try `enumerate<Word>()('are', 'some', 'these', 'words', 'some')` and it's valid.