# How to only allow unique string literal in array

Tags: typescript

```js
export interface IGUser {
  biography: string;
  id: string;
  ig_id: string;
  followers_count: number;
  follows_count: number;
  media_count: number;
  name: string;
  profile_picture_url: string;
  shopping_product_tag_eligibility: boolean;
  username: string;
  website: string;
}

const values: keyof IGUser = ['biography', ''];
```

[image]

How can I implement that I can only allow one instance of biography in the array?

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: This is not effectively expressible as a type. The first thing you should try is replacing it with an object literal, which is the right data structure for a set of unique keys. If you still want a tuple your options are: 1) A union of all possible tuple combinations (not efficient) 2) A constrained identity function or similar tool for enforcing type constraints, possibly paired with branded types to disallow bypassing validation (efficient but probably overcomplicated).

Comment: i was thinking about option 1 but yeah, it's very not efficient. and option 2 is, i don't have enough knowledge of typescript to do it. thank you!

Comment: @sailybra i think i will use object literals, i have no other option. thanks man! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with typing only, but you could run it through a function that strips out duplicates: [Delete duplicate elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747798/delete-duplicate-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: i already have this implemented, i was trying to achieve it with types only. but it's very hard or not possible? :( thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible but only to a certain amount of keys. At some point the calculation of that *unique array literal* type will become to expensice because it is dependent on the length of your [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (`keyof IGUser`). You'll get an *"Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite"* error.

Anyway, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63116449/12834972) by [Mu Tsun Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953396/mu-tsun-tsai) on the question *[Unordered tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852773/unordered-tuple-type)* I came up with the following. Using a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) you can ensure that all literals in your array are unique . You essentially compute all valid combination based on your initial object keys union. Note that this approach disallows any duplicate literals, not just `"biography"`

```
interface IGUser {
  biography: string;
  name: string;
  username: string;
//   id: string;
//   ig_id: string;
//   followers_count: number;
//   follows_count: number;
//   media_count: number;
//   profile_picture_url: string;
//   shopping_product_tag_eligibility: boolean;
//   website: string;
}

type SingleBiographyKeyArray<T extends string, R extends any[] = []> = R | {
    [K in T]: SingleBiographyKeyArray<Exclude<T, K>, [K, ...R]>
}[T];

let values: SingleBiographyKeyArray<keyof IGUser> = []; // valid
values = ["biography"] // valid
values = ["biography", "name", "username"] // valid

values = ["biography", "biography", "name"];
// ~~~ invalid
values = ["biography", "username", "name", "name"];
// ~~~ invalid
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHECqBnayDeAUMsgEbAD2A5lHAA4AWAngFzLZhShUDcxyIOAFsIbDlxC9%20AV1xRBIsZ258A9KpLJgAEyUSp6zcCoB9HXpWFDJGBQA2digHdo2EwgrTwbENKGloNQ0be0cnNw8vMB8-AKggzRFtYDh3T28BWMCrYOQ6KAoYYDsIEzpgBDBpKFLquwtJBJJsBgo6cskygu1pSpMwOFMIO2NgchGwVjIKewg4ECbkF1JsYEgGqQBfQkJJuhQAZW4SgCFKGnpmAGkIJgBBKFomAB4AFWQIAA9IEG1sdmUkgANMgAEofb4QX7-eZMADaAF1kABeZCIgB8KLByAAPgR%20CQ4VctCBkK8EWwjpJTudaIwmDd7o84C8AKKfBB2aTaCBvEFXdEgokggB0YtBCPRhE2cPJfEIJTAyAAbnAuRBsJTjhAztQ6ddbg8ns8ANa3QpoLByTGoxE8ZCGVUjbSEJ3SDVYuEAInIesuTC9SMdap0rrV7v%20tp9tP9XpBXoUEDjyC9smgicDDo0TtDYfVkbR0b99OTRYuJfjGYRCQAfnWSTmXW6PVHfeXmKW0-JhEnKz3S1Xa-XQI3CEA)

Comment: yeah you're right :( thanks man! appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a specific set of allowed values, you may do it like
https://tsplay.dev/NlXgrN

```
type ValidateUniqueArray<T, A extends T[]> =
  | A extends [infer F, ...infer L]
  ? (L extends Exclude<T, F>[]
    ? [F, ...ValidateUniqueArray<Exclude<T, F>, L>]
    : [F, Exclude<T, F>?]
  ) : [T?, ...unknown[]]
  ;

type ValidateCompleteUniqueArray<T, A extends any[]> =
  | [T] extends [never]
  ? []
  : A extends [infer F, ...infer L]
  ? (F extends T
    ? [F, ...ValidateCompleteUniqueArray<Exclude<T, F>, L>]
    : [T, ...ValidateCompleteUniqueArray<T, L>]
  ) : [T]
  ;

type conforms<T, V> = T extends V ? T : V;

function uniqueArray<T>() {
  return {
    partial<A extends T[]>(a: conforms<A, ValidateUniqueArray<T, A>>): A {
      return a as A;
    },
    complete<A extends T[]>(a: conforms<A, ValidateCompleteUniqueArray<T, A>>): A {
      return a as A;
    },
  }
}

let a1 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().partial([
  1, 2, 3, 4 // ok
])
let a2 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().partial([
  1, 1 // Type '1' is not assignable to type '2 | 3 | 4'.(2322)
])
let a3 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().partial([
  1, 'foo' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '2 | 1 | 3 | 4'.(2322)
])

let b1 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().complete([
  1, 2, 3, 4 // ok
])
let b2 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().complete([
  1, 2, 3, 1 // Type '1' is not assignable to type '4'.(2322)
])
let b3 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().complete([
  1, 2, 3, 'foo' // error
])
let b4 = uniqueArray<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>().complete([
  1, 2, 3 // Argument of type '[1, 2, 3]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[1, 2, 3, 4]'.
])
```

Comment: i will try this, thanks for helping :D

Comment: thanks man, this works! but not what i wanted but it works. thanks a lot :D