# Make an array element nullable in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am astonished not to have an error in this code:

```js
let myList: string[] = require('something')

let foo: string | undefined = myList[7]

foo.length // no error!
```

How can I make `foo` have type `string | undefined`?

I want the typescript compiler to raise `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` on the third line.

Comment: `undefined` and `null` are two different things. Do you want `string | undefined` or `string | null`? And what does that have to do with `foo.includes('')`? The empty string `''` is neither `null` nor `undefined`

Comment: [Nullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#nullable-types) refers to both undefined and null

Comment: I want tsc to say `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` on the third line

Comment: Forget about the empty string, it was to demonstrate that `foo` is considered as string, instead of `string | undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "cast" the result of the array access to `(string|undefined)`

```js
let myList : string[] = require('something');
let v = myList[7] as (string | undefined); //v will have type string|undefined
let uv = v.length;  //will give an error that v is possibly undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like TypeScript sees that `myList` is `string[]`, so `myList[7]` is detected to be of type `string`.

Although it's *assignable* to something of type `string | undefined`, TypeScript determines that it can't be undefined, so it automatically narrows the type of `foo` to `string` only.

If you wanted this to produce an error, you would have to type `myList` as `Array<string | undefined>`:

```
let myList: Array<string | undefined> = require('something')

let foo: string | undefined = myList[7]
console.log(foo);
foo.includes('') // Error
foo.length // Error
```

If you want TypeScript to understand that accessing past the end of the array will result in `undefined`, use a [tuple type instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140074):

```
let myList: [string, string] = require('something')
let foo = myList[7]
```

Then `foo` is typed as `undefined`, because it's past the length of the array.

If you don't know in advance how many elements the array has, the easiest way to get TypeScript to throw the error you want is really to type the array as `Array<string | undefined>`, since accessing any numeric index of the array may produce a string or undefined, despite the fact that the array's own-property values are all strings.

Comment: While it would work, I do not want this because it makes no sense: myList will only contain strings, forever

Comment: Only an out-of-bound access (`myList[n]` where `n >= myList.length`) would cause the element to be undefined

Comment: If it will only contain strings, then why do you want `foo` to be typed as `string | undefined`? That'd be inaccurate.

Comment: Because of out-of-bound access, I do not know if 7 (or another number) is lesser than the array length

Comment: @Bilow With that reasoning, every access to an array should be `sometype | undefined` That makes no sense. You are responsible for checking the bounds yourself.

Comment: Right, I want to check bounds, so I want to explicitly mark foo as nullable until I have performed the bounds check

Comment: Saw your edit. This is sad. So really no proper way to force cast foo to a nullable type?

Comment: @Bilow see my updated answer. Althoug IMHO one should check the array length before accessing a certain index. Most other languages will throw an error if you access an out of bound index. There may be reasons, this is handled differerent in JS

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance for the explanation on `so it automatically narrows the type of foo to string only.`

Comment: Sounds like OP wants "[pedantic index signatures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access)" as implemented in TS4.1.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't help me for situations where I wanted to push both `null` and a custom `Type` into the same array. This worked for me:

```
class MyClass {
    private myMixedArray: (number | null)[] = [];

    classMethod() {
        this.myMixedArray.push(42);
        this.myMixedArray.push(null);
    }
}
```