# How to specify the max length of an array in a typescript type (with distinct alternative types)?

Tags: typescript

```
type ValidValue = 'X' | 'Y';

type MyType = {
   arr: ValidValue[];
}
```

**How to enforce `arr` to have as max length `N` (2 in this case, because we have 2 valid distinct values)**

Comment: So is `['X', 'X']` acceptable or not?

Comment: @jcalz no, actually. they should not be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has fixed size array which called as [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) you can use optional element in tuple like this

```
let t: [number, string?, boolean?];
t = [42, "hello", true];
t = [42, "hello"];
t = [42];
```

also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495553/13729121) answer had more details about fixed-size arrays and you can find about typescript Types in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html).

Comment: I edited the question to specify that  I meant distinct values. is it possible to improve your answer based on that?

Comment: in that case, you can use SET data structure  which can store distinct values like List
 " const x = new Set<ValidValue>() "
refer this https://www.javatpoint.com/typescript-set

Answer (score 1):

### You can make use of [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) type like this:

```
type ValidValue = 'X' | 'Y';

type MyType = {
   arr: [ValidValue, ValidValue];
}

const obj :MyType = {
    arr: ['X', 'Y']  // <--- valid
}

const obj2 :MyType = {
    arr: ['X', 'Y', 'Y']  // <--- error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBN4IK7QLxQOQAaeUAPvgJp4DcAUDaJFALIgAq4OUA3jVH3ACcBALigBtdKnRYANLERTEWALq0AvnQDGAewB2AZ2BRtAIwBWUYS3aNcPPvyGixhPHLyVlfAPTeoAHgBaYKgANwUUGg0aHQMjUzMAJktrDig7XgdBEXFXd0p8vC8oXwDgwKgIIW0BKKA)

Comment: Is it still valid with a single element?

Comment: What did you mean by `single element`? like [string,string]?

Comment: The OP said `How to enforce arr to have as max length N` - if max length of the array is 2, that implies that you could have an array of length 1. `[<element>]`

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495285/typescript-restrict-maximum-array-length so if you need to also allow less-than-N length arrays, you could do `arr: [ValidValue?, ValidValue?];`

Answer (score 0):

Since array is an Object in Javascript you can extend the type using the intersection (&) to ensure the length of the array:

```
type ValidValue = 'X' | 'Y';

type MyType = {
   arr: ValidValue[] & { length: 2 };
}
```

This does however not prevent duplicated values in the array like `['X', 'X']`