# TS configuration for safe array access

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

In this code

```
const arr = ['hello', 'world'];
const x = arr[2];
const y = arr[0.5];
```

`arr` is a `string[]`, and `10` and `0.5` are `number`s, so TS implies that `10` and `0.5` can index `arr`, therefore inferring that `x` and `y` are `string`s too, while at runtime they'll be `undefined`.

Is there a configuration option I can write in my `tsconfig.json` that basically tells typescript "if you're not sure that `arr: T[]` has an element at `i`, do not infer that `arr[i]` is a `T`"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a Fixed length Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript)

Comment: No, as you can see from [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDMBTA7jAgkuATwB4wBXAWwCMMEA+ACgGYBKAKFElgA9V4kA2gEYADAF0O4aDEJ9ECASIB0AVjFA), this doesn't stop TS from inferring wrong types, even if the initial array size has been annotated

Comment: Please do keep reading past the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.1 introduced support for [*checked indexed accesses*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), which can be enabled via the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option.  If you turn that on, you get this behavior:

```
const arr = ['hello', 'world'];
const x = arr[10] // number | undefined
console.log(x.toUpperCase()) // compiler error
//          ~ <-- object is possibly undefined

console.log(x?.toUpperCase()) // okay
```

which is what you're looking for.  This option is *not* included in [the `--strict` suite of type checking features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), because it can make the compiler complain even for code which is generally considered safe:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].toUpperCase()) // error!
    // -------> ~~~~~~
    // arr[i] is possibly undefined
}
```

So you'll have to decide if your desired behavior is worth the possible false warnings from the type checker, and if so, turn on `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` explicitly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgBYFMA2+ImANDJgO4gL4AmmAugNwBQoksAHqvEugIwAGBjAD0omGACuAWwBGuZAB8YUsLVwAzAJZhctFiygIAnjADeLGNZjsIIfLgB0RAOYAKTk6ggAqgAd-RQBhOAhcdwBKSKsbcWsAPxgAHgBaVJgQOQArXGBYbQgYfxAICG05fDM1DR09AwBfWzgoYGwYd1xIi1jrOwdnN07u+O5C1XUtXX0WBrZwe0cXEA9OAH5vP0CQsIjosQkaqfrDeY4YMzREBHRBJwBWEXjpeUUYFSO6mcNNag7HAo8QRMGDaFK8BAuXBgVxQbAg7QAakR3UsNlsCwGyw813Q2gYmwCQQQoXCURGEkUCGoAEJegcYOkmekAHwwBIczn0+K4-GgoolMoVKoTWrTRpAA)