# How to create array of objects from another class in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two  angular classes called class A , B and I have an angular component

```
export class B {
    id:String;
    Name:String;
}
```

My class  A , Where I am passing data from a component. Where Component retrieves the data from httpclient request. Additionally I am trying to create an array of objects of class B . Which will have the size of data

```
export class A {

  mygroupB : B[];

  setData(data:any){
      if((data.length) >0){
        this.mygroupB = new B[data.length];
      }else return;

  }
}
```

But When I am running the code I am getting an error
"B[data.length] is not a constructor" . I can't figure out, what is the mistake here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should create object as `new B()`;  don't pass any arguments as your class B has no constructer to accept it.You can use `map` or loops to create a array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript

Comment: This is not java, you don't create array like that in javascript or typescript. Just `this.mygroupB = [];` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is you didn't instantiate your mygroupB before assigning the value. The next issue is you are trying to assign the value of data which is type ***any*** directly to mygroupB which has a type of ***B***.

In the solution below, I instantiated ***mygroupB*** before iterating the values of data and then pushing it to the ***mygroupB*** array.

```
setData(data: any) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
      this.mygroupB = new Array<B>();
      data.forEach(e => {
        this.mygroupB.push({
          Name: e.Name,
          id: e.id
        });
      });
      console.log(this.mygroupB);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help!