# Typescript fixed array with default values

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking for a way to create object Array that has a fixed size of 3 that fills it with default values but when i come to push into the array it should replace the default values.

**Example**:

Declare an array which fills the array with a string of "default value"

```
["default value", "default value", "default value"]
```

I now push some text to this initial array and expect the following:

```
["Added Data", "Default value", "Default Value"]
```

I push more data to this array and expect the following:

```
["Added Data", "Added Data", "Default Value"]
```

Again I push more data to this array and expect the following:

```
["Added Data", "Added Data", "Added Data"]
```

So the end result should be if push one data then the remainder of array should remain the default value unless i push all three data into the array.

**Note**: This example is a string array just to show an example but the solution i am looking for is array of objects.
The **Array.fill()** method works great for JavaScript immutable values like strings, numbers, and booleans. Array with objects, each slot in the array refers to the same object which is not what i am looking for. I want each object to be unique

Comment: Array.fill but it references the same object as i am doing an array of objects

Comment: This addresses fixed length array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript - but, doesn't address the array element substitution capability - you would need to build that on your own.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a normal array. You'll need to create a custom class or function.

Comment: Arrays don't work like this.  You might consider a circular buffer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: I suggest to implement your own implementation. One of the idea suggested on the second comment.

Comment: @helloworld just want to note, this question has little to do with typescript.

Comment: That's not "`push`ing" elements onto an array, that's `unshift`ing elements onto an array.

Comment: @hackape - but "fixed length arrays" does have everything to do with TypeScript - There is no such thing as a "fixed length array" in JavaScript - but in TypeScript arrays can be manipulated through typing enforcement - which also doesn't exist in JavaScript. But the OP is after a LIFO queue anyway - so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I’m just saying OP might be one who doesn’t clearly understand the relationship between TS and JS. This is what I read from the context. I used to spend time explaining, some many times that I’m kinda tired of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Array class to make it have the behavior you described...

```js
class FixedArray extends Array {

  /**
   * Contruct a fixed-length Array
   * @param int length - length of the array
   * @param mixed default_value - The default value for empty slots
   */
  constructor(length, default_value) {
    super(length);
    this.default_value = default_value;
    super.fill(default_value);
  }

  /**
   * "Push" items onto the begining of the array (unshift)
   * @params ...args mixed - values to put in the array
   */
  push(...args) {
    args.forEach(arg => {
      super.pop();
      super.unshift(arg);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Pop an item off the end of the array 
   * and replace it with the default value
   */
  pop(){
    super.pop();
    super.push(this.default_value);
  }

  /**
   * Shift an item off the start of the array 
   * and replace it with the default value
   */
  shift(){
    super.shift();
    super.unshift(this.default_value);
  }

}

var arr = new FixedArray(4, 'default value');
console.log(arr);

arr.push('new value');
console.log(arr);

arr.push('new value');
console.log(arr);

arr.pop();
console.log(arr);
```

And to address the part about the array's fill method, you cna add a method to just copy whatever value you put in it...

```js
/**
 * Fill the array with copies of whatever arguments are provided.
 * Fills by value, not by reference.
 */
fill(...args){
  args.forEach(arg=>{
    let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
    this.push(arg);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **primitive data types**' default value, follow below syntax

```js
const numList = new Array(10).fill(0)

console.log(numList)
console.log('Total items: ' + numList.length)
```

For **objects**'s default value, follow below syntax

```js
const objList = new Array(10).fill(0).map(()=> ({ a: 1, b: 2 }))

console.log(objList)
console.log('Total items: ' + objList.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create and fill the array with default unique object value:

```js
const tuple = new Array(3).fill(0).map(() => ({ foo: "bar" }))

// or
const defaultObject = { foo: "bar" }
const tuple = new Array(3).fill(0).map(() => ({ …defaultObject }))
```

To add new item, and keep array size constant

```js
function addTo(tuple, newItem) {
  tuple.unshift(newItem) // add new item to beginning 
  tuple.pop() // remove old item at the end
}
```

Comment: That will only work if you're hard-coding the object that you want to fill it with. If you're trying to fill it with an object that is stored in a variable this will do exactly the same thing as just passing the variable to the fill method.

Comment: the edit is an improvement, but any nested objects within that default object will still be passed by reference.

Comment: Updated to make it more obvious. OP doesn’t want same ref, so `.fill` doesn’t work, that’s why I use `.map`

Comment: You’re welcome to edit my answer and improve it. You got enough rep. 

Comment: I saw your update and responded to it. Editing answers isn't intended for changing the content of the answer, it's intended for things like reformatting. Besides, I already posted my own answer addressing this issue.

Comment: Hmm, I didn’t know the norm. Thanks for the heads-up, but I’d like to leave it as-is. The thing I’d like to highlight is the fill-then-map trick, not trying to guard everything, otherwise you might also want to add try…catch in your answer.

Comment: I was leaving a note to identify an potential issue for future readers, not because I expected you to change something. Teaching people how to catch errors is waaay out of the scope of this question.