# How to define array range of array of numbers in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

In Next.js I create a function component and use useState hook to declare variable for store array of digits like this

```js
const [digits, setDigits] = useState<number[]>();
```

But I also want to define the range of array generic, something like `Array(3)` (but not `[number, number, number]` because that is too long)

How to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a Fixed length Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript)

Comment: @ldruskis So the answer is CAN'T, right? Only tuple is works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const data = new Array<number>(100)
```

An array length of 100 where the elements have a type of `number`. Array comes with with a `fill` function to initialize your array if needed, for example

```
const array = new Array<number>(100).fill(9)
```

An array of length 100 where all indexes will be number 9.