# Fixed length array in TypeScript with reference to the length

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to define a type `foo` following this pseudo-code?

```
type foo<T> = {
  length: number;
  array: T[length]
}
```

Alternatively:

```
type foo<T> = {
  length: array.length;
  array: T[]
}
```

For example, `{length: 2, array: ["a","b"]}` should have this type, but `{length: 3, array: ["a","b"]}` should not.

It has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript) how to define a `FixedLengthArray<T,N extends number>` type. We can use this to define:

```
type foo<T,N extends number> = {
  length: N;
  array: FixedLengthArray<T,N>
}
```

This works when I want to define

```
let bar : foo<string,2> = {length: 2, array: ["a","b"]};
```

But my goal is to write

```
let bar : foo<string> = {length: 2, array: ["a","b"]};
```

Can we somehow let TypeScript infer the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript won't infer any generic parameter elsewhere than in a function call parameters. So you could use a function and [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html) in order to achieve that:

```
type Foo<U extends Array<any>, T extends [...U]> = {
    length: T['length'];
    array: T;
}

declare function handleFoo<U extends Array<any>, T extends [...U]>(param: Foo<U, T>): any;

handleFoo({ length: 3, array: ["a", "b"] }); // Error
handleFoo({ length: 2, array: ["a", "b"] }); // OK
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAVShAHsCA7AJgZygEEAnEgQxEXOxAD4AaKAFTUxwKgG0A6P5ALp0oAXigBvAFBQZUADY4A5sAAWALhZcA5AuzKVWgQG5ps8mUobmJgL6TJuCAGM556ADMArtifAAlnDYUCo0uArwSKgYWHiEpBRUNPRMrNEchLz8QgAUYObkALYaESgpdACUGkkmkiF44QjZ4vJKqhoAzEzmCRpcAETkfUx9AEZ9AlA25UZQAPSzUACiZHAktaENcE0tem1QAExdFiC9A0NQo%20OT03MLAPIA0kA)