# Using interface property as array length for another property in the same interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I've got this interface which will serve as props for a section component displaying different equipment. Each piece of equipment will be placed on a card inside a grid column.
Here's the interface:

```
interface EquipmentSectionProps {
  bgColor: "black" | "lightGrey";
  columns: number;
  category: string;
  products: string[];
  productImages: string[];
  productReferals: string[];
}
```

Given the property columns, I want to restrict the size of the arrays `products`, `productImages` and `productReferals` with the property `columns` since their disposal is correlated with the number of columns.

The obvious first thing to try was to pass the property column inside the array directly like this:

```
interface EquipmentSectionProps {
  bgColor: "black" | "lightGrey";
  columns: number;
  category: string;
  products: string[columns];
  productImages: string[columns];
  productReferals: string[columns];
}
```

however, the response comes back as

```
Cannot find name 'columns'.ts(2304) type columns = /*unresolved*/ any
```

Is there an easier way to make this possible without creating a duplicated interface and passing the property into the new one?

Comment: You could possibly make the interface generic in the type of `columns`, maybe as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBV0nN) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I gave a try to your solution and it works perfectly! Please go ahead of the answer.

Comment: But you've already accepted the other answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the interface [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `columns` property, and then define the corresponding array properties to be **[tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)** of the appropriate length.

In order to do this you'd need a utility type like `TupLen<N extends number, V>` which will resolve to a tuple of length `N` where every element is of type `V`:

```
interface EquipmentSectionProps<N extends number> {
  bgColor: "black" | "lightGrey";
  columns: N;
  category: string;
  products: TupLen<N, string>;
  productImages: TupLen<N, string>;
  productReferals: TupLen<N, string>;
}

const good: EquipmentSectionProps<3> = {
  bgColor: "black", category: "abc", columns: 3,
  products: ["a", "b", "c"],
  productImages: ["d", "e", "f"],
  productReferals: ["g", "h", "i"]
};

const bad: EquipmentSectionProps<3> = {
  bgColor: "black", category: "abc", columns: 3,
  products: ["a", "b", "c"],
  productImages: ["d", "e"], // error! 2 elements but requires 3
  productReferals: ["g", "h", "i", "j"] // error! 4 elements but only allows 3.
};
```

But there's no built in `TupLen<N, V>`; you have to write your own.  One way is as a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types):

```
type TupLen<N extends number, V = any, A extends V[] = []> =
    number extends N ? V[] : N extends A['length'] ? A : TupLen<N, V, [...A, V]>;

type TestNumber4 = TupLen<4, number>;
// type TestNumber4 = [number, number, number, number]
type TestBoolean2 = TupLen<2, boolean>;
// type TestBoolean2 = [boolean, boolean]
```

Also, if you don't want to have to write the column length twice, as in, `const v: EquipmentSectionProps<3> = { columns: 3, ⋯}` (once for the type argument and once for the `columns` property), you could instead write a helper function to *infer* the generic type argument from the value of the `columns` property:

```
const equipmentSectionProps = 
  <N extends number>(esp: EquipmentSectionProps<N>) => esp;

const good = equipmentSectionProps({
  bgColor: "black", category: "abc",
  columns: 3,
  products: ["a", "b", "c"],
  productImages: ["d", "e", "f"],
  productReferals: ["g", "h", "i"]
})
// const good: EquipmentSectionProps<3>

const bad = equipmentSectionProps({
  bgColor: "black", category: "abc",
  columns: 3,
  products: ["a", "b", "c"],
  productImages: ["d", "e"], // error, 
  // '[string, string]' is not '[string, string, string]'.
  productReferals: ["g", "h", "i", "j"] // error, 
  // '[string, string, string, string]' is not '[string, string, string]'.
})
// const good: EquipmentSectionProps<3>
```

You get the same behavior without needing to explicitly write out `EquipmentSectionProps<3>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIEcCuwAOBbCcAZQgTGAHsQAFKCnAZwB4A5ZCAD0hABMHkQmPACNoAPmQBvAFDI5yYQHMAwhQA2FKAC5kAImFrEAa13IAPnrXBFACzABxKBACeugNyz5CdUJAMdLB7yyAhwkIqazjoMYFCgikHyOHQ8mGT+yAAqmDgAMoSsADTIMXEgimKJcskUqWQAknhwihAZ2XkFLMWl8ZWe1SlpYABKEDDQcGptOfkgRSWxvR4AvtJr3n5gyABuOhjY+IRgJGSUNHSMTADMEgC8Uv0KKuqaOvqGCCbFoeGRb3DCBC6b4+PB+HRXQqPGp1MAZADaujgwL0whRuiBAF0ocEYUNGs1WjpETx0RB0TBdNjoYMyKNxlBJgjdIp0TZ0cAqdJlh5pBsYsgAO57LC4AjEUjkKi0ejMG7Ie4yYJKVQabSoj5fEJhCARKBRPQAoEgtS+DKQmm1IbM5HFfTorE4pK0sAElrM0l28nY5AAel97CgdCgAEJkAAmdhqCDiuEKTBbJyipz8K6W2H0iZTYkstkc9EAKypfoD0GDYYALFGY0d+MIE8gqGpnMhJhpBamAHTc3nSMDOHAodqzVjsLiEPgCISiKDFABqCtbIGcxQAgmPuJO5-DMYud3dHoIRNANxP+GwAPzIbe7gKn3j8VfwgDk0fKYBsz93V-XOmHnXnYp4U7EDV3nTE+j7Ach1aMAWGnaAq3uf85grYojxnPp-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)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't restrict the length of an array via Typescript types (e.g. interface declarations like the one you're showing). You'll have to write the length checks inside the code for your component.

Even though there's a way to [initialize an array with a specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140074/1563240) in javascript, there's no enforcement within javascript that can make the length immutable. Nothing is stopping the array from being lengthened, which means you need to check the length explicitly as-needed.