Type with a fixed length array whose length depends on a type property value
If I have a type as follows:
type MyType = {
  index: number;
  label: string;
  nbClouds: number;
  clouds: Cloud[];
};

export default MyType;

Is it possible to enforce the length of clouds with the value of nbClouds?

In general this is probably not possible. This thread has some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript. The problem is that the type exists at compile time, while the value of nbClouds exists only at runtime.

You can infer the amount of tuple items (nbClouds) using a generic type and then use a recursive conditional type to compute the clouds tuple like so:
type Cloud = {};

type CloudsTuple<
  N extends number,
  R extends Cloud[] = [],
> = R['length'] extends N ? R : CloudsTuple<N, [Cloud, ...R]>;

type MyType<NBClounds extends number> = {
  index: number;
  label: string;
  nbClouds: NBClounds;
  clouds: CloudsTuple<NBClounds>;
};

type Example = MyType<5>;
// type Example = {
//     index: number;
//     label: string;
//     nbClouds: 5;
//     clouds: [Cloud, Cloud, Cloud, Cloud, Cloud];
// }

TypeScript Playground

Nice! CloudsTuple is better than GrowToSize in my answer. The author needs to decide if he is happy with clouds.push({}); being potentially unsafe.

You can define something like this:
type GrowToSize<T, N extends number, A extends T[]> = 
  A['length'] extends N ? A : GrowToSize<T, N, [...A, T]>;

export type FixedArray<T, N extends number> = GrowToSize<T, N, []>;

And use it like this:
interface Cloud {
    someProp: string;
}

type MyType<N extends number> = {
  index: number;
  label: string;
  nbClouds: N;
  clouds: FixedArray<Cloud, N>;
};

var myVar1: MyType<2> = {
    index: 1,
    label: "test",
    nbClouds: 2,
    clouds: [  // ERROR
        { someProp: "" },
    ]
};

var myVar2: MyType<2> = {
    index: 1,
    label: "test",
    nbClouds: 2,
    clouds: [  // OK
        { someProp: "" },
        { someProp: "" },
    ]
};

Unfortunately, there is no way to infer the length at compile time. The above is not safe in all scenarios.
myVar2.clouds.push({ someProp: "" }); // Still a problem

You can create something that is runtime-safe:
class RuntimeSafeArray<T, A extends T[], const N extends number = A['length']> {
    private _arr: A;
    private _len: N;
    constructor(length: N) {
        this._len = length;
        this._arr = [] as any;
    }
    push(item: T) {
        if (this._arr.length >= this._len) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        this._arr.push(item);
    }
    set(items: A) {
        if (items.length > this._len) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        this._arr = items; 
    }
   // TODO implment get, length and other method...
}

function makeSafe<T, A extends T[], const N extends number = A['length']>(
    index: number, label: string, nbClouds: N, clouds: A
) {
        return {
            index,
            label,
            nbClouds,
            clouds: new RuntimeSafeArray<T, A>(nbClouds)
        } as MyType<N>;
}

And use it like this:
const unsafeVar = {
    index: 1,
    label: "test",
    nbClouds: 2 as const,
    clouds: [ { someProp: "" }, { someProp: "" } ]
}

var myVar = makeSafe(
    unsafeVar.index, unsafeVar.label, unsafeVar.nbClouds, unsafeVar.clouds
);
myVar.clouds.set([{ someProp: "" }, { someProp: "" } ]); // OK
myVar.clouds.set([{ someProp: "" }, { someProp: "" },  { someProp: "" }]); // Error
myVar.clouds.push({ someProp: "" }); // Error (at runtime)

